# Remove class from editable area

Tags: ckeditor

Im need to remove class from editable area (cke_textarea_inline) in my plugin.

```
    var command = editor.addCommand('command', {
        exec: function(editor) {
            //remove class... HOW?
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as: `editor.editable().removeClass( 'cke_textarea_inline' );`.